# How to create Websocket Java SE client?

Tags: java, html, websocket

My problem is that not since a Websocket creates client in Java SE to be able to connect to the Websocket HTML5 server.

Ningun example I dress in Internet they me have worked.

**Code in HTML5**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var mysocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");

            mysocket.onopen = function (evt){
                escribir("Websocket abierto");
            };

            mysocket.onmessage = function (evt){
                escribir("RECIBIDO: " + evt.data);    
            };

            mysocket.onclose = function (evt){
                escribir("Websocket cerrado");
            };

            mysocket.onerror = function (evt) {
                escribir("ERROR: " + evt.data);
            }

            function escribir(texto){
                valor = document.getElementById("caja").value;
                document.getElementById("caja").value = valor + texto + "\n";
            }

            function enviar(texto) {
                mysocket.send(texto);
                escribir("ENVIADO: " + texto);
            }

            function desconectar(){     
                mysocket.close();
            }
        </script>
```

I have tried Jetty and it me has not worked.
Do you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

In java there are some options, if you aren't interested in secure websocket server, then [this link](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjthPCAw-zOAhXJVh4KHd39AwYQFghGMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjava-websocket.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNGOuozSbWH4-bkGwdZeKqrppZLWlQ&sig2=rA-8LstzGbI8EWzu4BMG0Q&bvm=bv.131286987,d.dmo) can help you. There are enough examples.

PD: You can try Jetty, using some dependencies needed for websocket.